# Busca insensível ao digitar no INPUT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o mecanismo de busca em JavaScript abaixo. O problema é que quando escrevo a palavra "**tomato**" ele busca a palavra "**tomatoes**". Provavelmente é um problema de sensibilidade ou está pegando apenas parte da palavra digitada. Seria possível corrigir isso usando apenas JavaScript ou jQuery?

```js
$("#box").on('keyup', function() {
   var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
 $('.connect-cat').show().not(function() {
    return matcher.test($(this).find('.name, .category').text())
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder='Search' id='box' type='text' />
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
 <span class='name'>tomatoes</span>
</div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
 <span class='name'>tomato</span>
</div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
 <span class='name'>apple</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno que você espera da função dentro do `.not()` deve ser um **elemento**, um **seletor** ou uma **array** ([documentação do `.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)). Da forma que está, o retorno está sendo um booleano *true* ou *false*, que não tem efeito no método.

Altere o `return` para um ternário que devolverá o próprio elemento (se a condição for `true`) ou *null* (se for `false`). Ou seja, devolvendo o próprio elemento, ele não sofrerá o `.hide()` posterior.

```
return matcher.test($(this).find('.name, category').text()) ? $(this) : null;
```

Em relação à busca, há duas formas de resolver isso:

**1.** Usando `.test()`:

Retire a flag `g` (*global*), porque o comportamento desta flag com `.test` e `.exec` é diferente de `.match` ([documento para ter uma noção disso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)).

```js
$("#box").on('keyup', function(){
   var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
   $('.connect-cat').show().not(function(){
       return matcher.test($(this).find('.name, category').text()) ? $(this) : null;
   }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder='Search' id='box' type='text' />
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>tomatoes</span>
</div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>tomato</span>
</div>

<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>tomatos</span>
</div>

<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>apple</span>
</div>
```

**2.** Usando `.match()`:

```js
$("#box").on('keyup', function(){
   var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
   $('.connect-cat').show().not(function(){
      return $(this).find('.name, category').text().match(matcher) ? $(this) : null;
   }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder='Search' id='box' type='text' />
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>tomatoes</span>
</div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>tomato</span>
</div>

<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>tomatos</span>
</div>

<div class='connect-cat'>
   <span class='name'>apple</span>
</div>
```

### Edit

> Só para reforçar e ao contrário o que afirma a outra resposta, a flag
>   `g` **TEM SIM A VER** com a forma que o `.test()` trabalha, conforme
>   pode-se ver [nesta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex), que informo novamente. Me parece que o
>   nosso amigo da outra resposta não leu, ou leu e não entendeu.

Também conforme [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604884/1377664) no SOen:

> When you use a global flag on a JS RegExp the "test" and "exec"
>   methods each halt at the first match but keep a pointer to where they
>   stopped searching in the string. That pointer can be inspected on the
>   lastIndex property. When you call "test" or "exec" again it begins
>   searching for a match starting at the lastIndex.
>
> So, when you test a RegExp on a string that matches the entire string
>   the lastIndex is set to the end of the string. The next time you test
>   it starts at the end of the string, returns false, and sets lastIndex
>   back to zero.

Tradução livre:

> Quando você usa a *flag global* (`g`) em um regex de JavaScript, ambos
>   os métodos "test" e "exec" param na primeira correspondência e mantêm
>   essa posição na busca pela string. Essa posição pode ser verificada na
>   propriedade lastIndex. Quando você chama o "teste" ou "exec"
>   novamente, a busca irá iniciar da última posição verificada (*cito:
>   isso explica o mau funcionamento que estava ocorrendo*).
>
> Logo, quando você testa um RegExp numa string que irá casar toda a
>   string, o lastIndex será no final da string. A próxima vez que você
>   testar, irá iniciar no final da string, retornando *false*, e
>   redefinindo o lastIndex de volta a zero.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira que usou regex

```
new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
```

Com certeza o uso de regex assim vai dar problema sempre, pois você não tem controle sobre valor de `val()`

Inclusive o problema de "tomato" encontrar "tomatoes" é porque não existe os "delimitadores" `^` e `$` no começo e fim da regex, e só pra constar, **o problema não tem nada haver** com o modificador `g`.

Fora que é muita complexidade sem necessidade, bastaria usar `.toLowerCase` em ambos valores comparados, exemplo:

```js
$("#box").on('keyup', function() {
    var matcher = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

 $('.connect-cat').show().not(function() {
    return matcher == $(this).find('.name, .category').text().toLowerCase()
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder='Search' id='box' type='text' />
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
 <span class='name'>tomatoes</span>
</div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
 <span class='name'>tomato</span>
</div>
   
<div class='connect-cat'>
 <span class='name'>apple</span>
</div>
```

---

Se a intenção for buscar palavras que comecem com o que foi digitado pode usar `.indexOf() == 0`

```
var matcher = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

$('.connect-cat').show().not(function() {
   return matcher.indexOf( $(this).find('.name, .category').text().toLowerCase() ) == 0
}).hide();
```

Se a intenção for buscar palavras que contenham parte do que foi digitado pode usar `.indexOf() != -1`

```
var matcher = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

$('.connect-cat').show().not(function() {
   return matcher.indexOf( $(this).find('.name, .category').text().toLowerCase() ) != -1
}).hide();
```

Comment: @dvd então você pensa geralmente em votar pelas pessoas e pela empatia que tem por elas e não pelo conteúdo e qualidade do conteúdo? Interessante saber.

Comment: @dvd aonde exatamente não esta funcionando, eu ficaria muito grato se explicasse aonde falhou, será que é diferença no Firefox, ou falhou no Internet explorer?

Comment: @dvd O que eu respondi foi o que entendi do que o AP queria (que na verdade não esta muito claro), eu entendi que não deveria aparecer tomatoes quando digitar tomato, então me parece que a palavra digitada teria que ser exata, mas se não vou isso eu vou aceitar sua critica sim, pois se o entendimento foi errado da minha parte é muito justo e louvável criticar e receber criticas ;)